# textarea drag combined with textarea below

Tags: html, css

**question 1:** When I drag down the top-left textarea, the bottom-left textarea falls. I want the bottom-left textarea to move together with top-left textarea. How can I do this?

**question 2:** When I drag down the top-right textarea, the left-bottom textarea starts moving. How can I prevent this?

**http://jsfiddle.net/4BX6u/**

```
<div class="container">
            <textarea class="area1"></textarea>
            <textarea class="area1"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="container">
            <textarea class="area1"></textarea>
            <textarea class="area1"></textarea>
</div>




.container
{
    width: 820px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}

.area1
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    resize: vertical;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `float` in your css to stop it from extending.

Comment: Haha my bad completely, Josh is right I did a typo the solution is to remove your float completely. The inline bit did literally nothing, and adding it in just stopped it from working as I was incorrect :)

Comment: thank you very much. I put the fiddle of your code, so other people might benefit from it as well.

Comment: No problem, make sure you don't still have the display: inline in your code too, I can imagine you going around making sure its included in the future when its actually pointless :D

Comment: @SimonStaton It doesn't have the display inline. You can approve my edit. Thank you very much.